# Hyper-V not appearing in Windows Features VMWare not working due to minimum requirements not meet | Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm using Windows 10 Home (Version 2004) After I updated to 2004 VMWare (Version 16) doesn't work. If I try to start a VM it says "Your host does not meet minimum requirements to run VMware Player with Hyper-V or Device/Credential Guard enabled. Refer to VMware KB article 76918 at https://kb.vmware.com/kb/76918 for more details." So I try disabling Hyper-V in my Windows Features , but sadly there where no Hyper-V in the Windows Features (The option dose simply not exist! No Checkbox with Hyper-V). I also try doing it via PowerShell but that doesn't work ether. I disabled Virtual Machine Platform but no results! Can some one help?

Comment: Yes, that's the wired thing, I got this Issue even I have Windows 10 Home! So there should not be an Hyper-V, but it has mead trouble! Sorry for not providing the version of VMWare, but actually, it doesn't matter! This issue appeared in every Version of VMWare

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because an unknown or unspecified Windows update was reported to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So, actually solved it myself! Simply updating Windows 10 solves it for me!

Answer (score -1):

Run PowerShell as administrator then use the following command and then restart your windows

> bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

this will fix your problem.